# Contradiction on findings in existing literature

Tags: thesis, supporting-information

I'm currently writing my thesis where I have two underlying sources where one says that a variable (has the founder of a kickstarter project backed other projects?) has influence on the dependent variable, while another source says it doesn't. What do I do in such a situation?

Comment: Quote them both or figure out which is correct and why. Simple. (no, not really)

Comment: The conflict between the two sources is a good research topic by itself. Only one can be correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Buffy notes, you cite both, and expound upon the apparent conflict.

If you are just reviewing literature, you would point out that the two studies came to different conclusions. If this is on-topic for your thesis, you would then dig a bit deeper and clarify what the studies have in common and how they differ, as it would lay out potential explanations for the apparent conflict.

This sort of thing is often the goal of reviewing literature to start with - identify a gap where there are no studies, or identify places where studies and/or theory seems to disagree.

Depending on what work you are doing, you may simply note this as a promising topic for future research, or you may want to try to address this conflict yourself with your own work to try to resolve the contradiction. The answer may be all kinds of things, from seeking out a mediating variable, to changing the analysis in a way that makes the conflict disappear, to ending up confirming that in fact "sometimes this variable matters, and sometimes it doesn't, and we don't know why."

Comment: Thank you for the broad answer, helps to understand the underlying logic behind each decision. In my case, the variable is only of secondary importance so I will simply note this as an interesting finding

Answer (score 5):

A statistics caution: "not significant" does not mean "not different" or "not related."

If one study reports *X and Y are significantly correlated, p=0.01*, and another study reports *X and Y are not significantly correlated, p=0.23* **these results are not necessarily in conflict**.

You likely don't need to go through a whole meta analysis procedure in your thesis' literature review if that isn't a major objective, but you should consider apparently conflicting information carefully to make sure it is actually in conflict, including both methodological differences and the effects of random sampling and sample size.

Comment: Yes, I was about to leave this answer myself. It's unusual to directly show that variables are unrelated, they instead show no evidence of association. One way to see if there's a conflict is to look at effect size and sample size. From the study that found significant association, you can find the effect size of the association. Using that and the sample size from the other study, you can calculate power. If the second study is underpowered, the fact that they find no association is unsurprising - they did not collect enough data. If they did have enough data, only then is there a conflict.

Comment: @NuclearWang Right. Even then they may not be in conflict, because effect size estimates from a single study can be very imprecise. But yes, you can use the power estimate approach to at least figure out how likely the second study would be to miss an effect similar in size to the one observed in the first study. Even if both studies are appropriately powered and assuming the effect is real i.e. null is false, according to some standard power threshold like 80% you'd by definition expect 20% of the studies to fail to reject the null hypothesis.

Comment: +1 very true, and this of course also comes up in regression models where many variables are dumped in and some aren't "significant", but may or may not improve the model depending on the comparison metric used, etc.